# Question on orthonormal bases and the outer product in $\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ with orthonormal bases $| u_1 \rangle, \dots, | u_n \rangle $.

I know that for $i \neq j$, $ \langle u_i  | u_j \rangle = 0$. Is there any corresponding identity for the outer product $| u_i \rangle  \langle u_j |$?

In $\mathbb{R}^n$ I might switch to the standard basis and note that $| e_i \rangle \langle e_i |$ is a diagonal square matrix with 1 at the $i$th diagonal (and zero everywhere else). Is there a similar nice basis for $\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$?

(My ultimate goal is to find a transformation from $\langle u_i | A | u_j \rangle$ to $\langle v_i | A | v_j \rangle$, where $| v_1 \rangle, \dots, | v_n \rangle $ is another orthonormal basis for $A$. I thought maybe I could simplify something like $| u_i \rangle  | \langle u_i | A | u_j \rangle \langle u_j |$.)

Comment: $\Bbb C^n$ also has a "standard" (orthonormal) basis for any positive-definite Hermitian form $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$. For the last part, maybe something like [this](https://www.phenix.bnl.gov/WWW/publish/seto/quantum/qm12.pdf) (beginning of page 3) would be helpful, notation is the same. Though I can already see a typo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that the "corresponding identity" is the fact that for an orthonormal basis $\{|u_1\rangle ,\dots,|u_n \rangle\}$, the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n |u_i \rangle\langle u_i|$ is the identity operator. I don't think that there is anything generally useful to be said about individual outer products $|u_i\rangle \langle u_j |$ except for the fact that the trace of such an outer product is equal to $\langle u_j|u_i \rangle = \delta_{ij}$.

Regarding your "ultimate goal", note that for any $i,j$, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\langle v_i |A|v_j \rangle &=
\langle v_i |\left[\sum_{p = 1}^n |u_p \rangle\langle u_p|\right]
A
\left[\sum_{q = 1}^n |u_q \rangle\langle u_q|\right]|v_j \rangle
\\ & = \sum_{p,q = 1}^n \langle v_i|u_p \rangle\langle u_p| A| u_q\rangle\langle u_q|v_j \rangle
\\ & = \sum_{p,q = 1}^n \langle u_p|v_i\rangle^* \langle u_q|v_j \rangle\langle u_p|A|u_q \rangle,
\end{align*}
$$
where $z^*$ denotes the complex conjugate of a complex number $z$.

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind explaining how you get from the second to the third line?

Comment: @Sirch From the second to the third line, I'm just rearranging a product of numbers and using the fact that $\langle y|x \rangle = \langle x|y \rangle^*$.